# C++ odbc close recordset leaks memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, odbc, recordset

In my application I'm facing memory leaks. The full application is multi threaded and each thread connects to same DB (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 SP3) through ODBC driver 13.1. The application opens and dynamically closes the record set it needs.

I'm investigating my code and now I'm pointing the finger to record set `Close()` function. I wrote this sample code that cause memory leak to me.

CCellsSet is a Consumer ODBC MFC class made by visual studio wizard that inherits from CRecordset.

I've also tried with more recent SQL Server versions but I had same scenario.

On my machine each pair rs.Open() and rs.Close() cause a leak around 1Kb.

Here reference to [Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/crecordset-class?view=vs-2017#open) and [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/crecordset-class?view=vs-2017#close) on msdn, in reference to it calling Close() should be enough to avoid leaks.

```
void Test(CDatabase* ptr_db)
{
    CCellsSet rs;

    rs.m_pDatabase = ptr_db;

    rs.Open();

    rs.Close();
}

int main()
{
    CDatabase DB;

    DB.OpenEx("DSN=__myDNS__;UID=sa;PWD=__myPWD__", CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);

    for (long i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        printf("loop '%d' \n", i);

        Test(&DB);
    }

    if (DB.IsOpen())
    {
        DB.Close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to profile the code using a leak checker like Deleaker?

Comment: If you run this code in an infinite loop (`while (true) { ... } `), does it eat all the memory?

Comment: actually when I ran the code in an infinite loop memory was growing at the beginning, but after couple of 10 thousand iterations it stabilize to certain value.

I ttryed other free leak detectors, now I requested for a trial license of your one.

Answer (score 0):

When not passing a CDatabase* when constructing the CCellsSet, an object of that type is created. Afterwards the pointer to that object is overwritten by you. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/crecordset-class?view=vs-2017#crecordset

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to deleaker! It helps me to focus where real leaks were.

In fact code I posted before wasn't leak in memory